# pretty print data class in JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dart, encoding, pretty-print

I did not find much about pretty printing to indent the JSON in order to make it better readable, and what I found was either not fit for (my) purpose or not sufficiently clear to me.

So, how do I stream/store/print a JSON string in a reader friendly matter?

Answer (score 0):

given you have a data class (possibly with a complex nested structure underneath) `MyClass myClass;` and you want to transform it into an indented string with line breaks.

What I used `final jsonString = jsonEncode(myClass);` for is now replaced by

```dart
  const JsonEncoder encoder = JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ');
  final jsonString = encoder.convert(myClass);
```